# Different gdb results

Tags: buffer-overflow, binary-code

I'm trying to use overthewire narnia problems as a way to learn about binary exploitation and I'm getting different results than any of the walkthroughs

I was looking at https://tuonilabs.wordpress.com/2017/05/13/overthewire-narnia-write-up/ for 'Level 2' and started off by used peda to create a pattern - I ran the program with this pattern and it segfaulted - I used `x/s $esp` in gdb and got the value from the stack pointer - ran pattern offset on it and it returned 136 instead of the 140 value they say. I also just generated a string of 132 A's and 4 b's and again - it works out.

I then look at https://triedal.github.io/narnia-writeup/ for Level2 and they start off using gdb to disassemble and workout the overflow that way - so I do so and my assembly code is different to theirs!

```
    Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804844b <+0>: push   ebp
   0x0804844c <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x0804844e <+3>: add    esp,0xffffff80
   0x08048451 <+6>: cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1
   0x08048455 <+10>:    jne    0x8048471 <main+38>
   0x08048457 <+12>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x0804845a <+15>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x0804845c <+17>:    push   eax
   0x0804845d <+18>:    push   0x8048520
   0x08048462 <+23>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048467 <+28>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x0804846a <+31>:    push   0x1
   0x0804846c <+33>:    call   0x8048320 <exit@plt>
   0x08048471 <+38>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x08048474 <+41>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x08048477 <+44>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x08048479 <+46>:    push   eax
   0x0804847a <+47>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x80]
   0x0804847d <+50>:    push   eax
   0x0804847e <+51>:    call   0x8048310 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048483 <+56>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x08048486 <+59>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x80]
   0x08048489 <+62>:    push   eax
   0x0804848a <+63>:    push   0x8048534
   0x0804848f <+68>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048494 <+73>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x08048497 <+76>:    mov    eax,0x0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

so in mine the call is at main+51 not main+70

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this related to your other question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200353/shellcode-different-on-guide